# Disable Close Button

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a form that a user uses to select the level when a Game starts. I want to disable the close button such that a user cannot close the form (The user will click some buttons to select the level).

I have been able to stop the user from closing the form if a button is not clicked using

```
    bool _Next = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
        button2.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
        button3.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

    }

    void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        if (btn == button1)
        {
            Level(1);
        }
        else if (btn == button2)
        {
            Level(2);
        }
        else if (btn == button3)
        {
            Level(3);
        }
        _Next = true;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_Next == true)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

This is quite long. I want to know if there is any way i can just disable or hide the form close button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the Controls of the form with:

```
this.ControlBox = false;
```

The above will remove the `maximize`, `minimize` and `close button` from the right upper corner.

The above is also accessible on the Visual Studio when you select the form itself at the properties tab.

You can override the `OnClosing` method:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_Next)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already disabling the close button. In your `FormClosing` event you cancel the event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This code works perfectly; I just tested it to make sure.